# Interfaces with construct signatures not type checking

Tags: typescript

I've been playing a bit with interfaces with construct signatures in TypeScript, and I became a bit confused when the following failed to type check:

```
class Foo {
    constructor () {
    }
}

interface Bar {
    new(): Bar;
}

function Baz(C : Bar) {
    return new C()
}

var o = Baz(Foo);
```

The type error is:

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
>   Construct signatures of types 'new() => Foo' and 'Bar' are
>   incompatible: Type 'Bar' requires a construct signature, but Type
>   'Foo' lacks one (C: Bar) => Bar

The type of Foo's constructor is () => Foo, and that is what I thought that Bar said. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an updated version of your code with a subtle change.

We define the `Bar` interface with whatever functions and variables we expect to be present.

Next, we extend the `Bar` interface with the `NewableBar` interface. This just defined a constructor that returns a `Bar`.

Because `Foo` implements `Bar` and has a constructor and `Baz` requires a `NewableBar`, everything is checked.

This is a little more verbose than `any` - but gives you the checking you want.

```
interface Bar {

}

interface NewableBar extends Bar {
    new();
}

class Foo implements Bar {
    constructor () {

    }
}

function Baz(C : NewableBar) {
    return new C()
}

var o = Baz(Foo);
```

Comment: Instead of using `any` you use a super interface (you can leave out the `implements` and `extends`, btw). That's alright, I guess, and better than `any`, but one thing still bugs me: Why can't you let `NewableBar::new()` return a `NewableBar`? Why does it have to be a type which is **more generic** than `NewableBar` (and obviously at least as generic as `Foo`)?

Comment: @AdrianLang I put in the explicit inheritance and implementations to be explicit, but you are correct - TypeScript will happily infer those if everything matches. There is an interpretation issue when trying to treat a `new()` signature on a method as a particular type.

Comment: But, this breaks whenever you try to add anything to Foo.
Edit: sorry, I was doing it wrong. My construct signature should be: `new(... _ : any[]) : Bar;`

Comment: This is really because an uninitialized `Foo` doesn't have the functions that are created when you initialize it, so `Foo` is not substitutable for `new Foo()`. I will post an alternate solution in a different answer based on where I think you are going with this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem (at least from the TypeScript compiler's point of view) is the signature of `Bar`'s `new` method. If you replace the definition of `Bar` with the following,

```
interface Bar {
  new (): any;
}
```

it works. You might as well use `new (): Foo`, just `Bar` as return value does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I had a need for something similar today and came across post. After some trial and error I came up with the following solution:

```
interface Bar { 
    sayHello(name: string);
}

class Foo implements Bar {
    sayHello(name: string) {
        window.alert("Hello " + name);
    }
}

function Baz(c: new() => Bar) {
    return new C();
}

var o = Baz(Foo);
o.sayHello("Bob");
```

Basically interfaces can only define the contract of an instance of an object, so requiring a certain constructor to exist must be done at the function that will be calling the constructor. This method also plays nicely with generics:

```
function Baz<T extends Bar>(c: new() => T) {
    return new c();
}

var o = Baz(Foo);
```

In the example above the variable "o" will be inferred as type Foo.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know where you are taking this and I think you need a subtly different approach.

This example says the following:

- Baz **must** be passed an item that is newable.
- Baz **will** return a Bar
- Not all Bar's need to be newable, only those being passed to Baz

Here is the example:

```
interface Bar {
    sayHello(name: string): void;
}

interface Newable {
    new();
}

class Foo implements Bar {
    constructor () {

    }

    sayHello(name: string) {
        window.alert('Hello ' + name);
    }
}

function Baz(C : Newable) {
    return <Bar> new C()
}

var o = Baz(Foo);
o.sayHello('Bob');
```

The only danger of this approach is that you could pass something newable that wasn't a Bar to the Baz function. As you are using a dynamic feature by creating an object from an argument, this is largely unavoidable unless you are willing to pass in a pre-initialized object, in which case Baz would quite happily just accept a Bar, rather than a newable.

Comment: Yes, something along these lines was what I wanted to achieve. With the exception that I wanted to `Bar` and `Newable` to be one interface. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple answer really. Look at your `Bar` interface:

```
interface Bar {
    new(): Bar;
}
```

Let's say you have managed to create some `Magic` class that implements this interface.

```
class Magic implements Bar {
    // ...
}
```

What this means is that any instance of `Magic` must adhere to the specification of `Bar`. So let's say you have an instance of `Magic` called `magic`.

Since `magic` adheres to the specification of `Bar`, `magic` must be newable, which means the following must work:

```
const foo = new magic() // lowercase m!
```

Also, the result of that call, i.e. `foo`, must itself adhere to `Bar`. This means that the following must also work:

```
const zzz = new foo();
```

And then it is clear that the following must also work:

```
new (new (new (new (new (new (new (new Magic())))))))
```

And it is clear that your code doesn't fulfill this condition. Therefore, your code does not type check.