# Multiple inheritance workarounds

Tags: abstract-class, typescript, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to discover a pattern for combining multiple interfaces into one abstract class.  Presently I can combine multiple interfaces via `implements`, but an interface cannot declare a constructor.  When I must introduce a constructor I'm forced to use an abstract class.  When I use a abstract class I must re-declare the entire composite interface! Surely I'm missing something?

```
interface ILayerInfo {
    a: string;
}

interface ILayerStatic {
    b(): string;
}

class Layer implements ILayerInfo, ILayerStatic {
    constructor(info: ILayerInfo);
    a: string;
    b(): string;
}
```

**ANSWER**: Use `new`:

```
interface Layer extends ILayerInfo, ILayerStatic {
    new(info: ILayerInfo);
}

// usage: new Layer({ a: "" });
```

Comment: Maybe an InstanceType<Type> could be useful here somehow. Reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25998

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Declaring a constructor on the same interface as the instance members doesn't really make much sense -- if you're going to pass in a type dynamically to use in a constructor, it's the static side of the class that would be restricted. What you would want to do is probably something like this:

```
interface Colorable {
    colorize(c: string): void;
}

interface Countable {
    count: number;
}

interface ColorCountable extends Colorable, Countable {
}

interface ColorCountableCreator {
    new(info: {color: string; count: number}): ColorCountable;
}

class ColorCounted implements ColorCountable {
    count: number;
    colorize(s: string) { }
    constructor(info: {color: string; count: number}) {
        // ...
    }
}

function makeThings(c: ColorCountableCreator) {
    var results: ColorCountable[];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        results.push(new c({color: 'blue', count: i}));
    }
    return results;
}

var items = makeThings(ColorCounted);
console.log(items[0].count);
```

See also [How does typescript interfaces with construct signatures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407036/how-does-typescript-interfaces-with-construct-signatures-work)

Comment: It was the "new" keyword on the interface that I was missing!  I didn't want the class at all.  With "new" I can stick to interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample of a solution for inheriting multiple interfaces:

```
type ShowAllWithTypography =  TypographyClampProps & ShowAllProps

interface Props extends ShowAllWithTypography
```

Comment: Yes, or you could do `interface Props extends TypographicClampProps, ShowAllProps` but that does not help with class inheritance, which does not allow for multiple base classes.

Comment: I think see what you're saying. This solution was for expecting props types in a react project, where I wanted to expect certain props in Child components, but extend the properties of my Props interface a bit further.

This worked for me but your use case needs a constructor, yes?

Comment: I was using libraries written before typescript that used mixins as a way of implementing multiple inheritance.  I needed to describe them, specifically the constructor.  I used "new" in the interface to describe the constructor.  I think your answer is addressing the question in a way I'm not understanding.  It seems you're missing a "new" declaration.

Comment: Anything given the Props return type will have all the properties of ShowAllWithTypography. I could extend it further by using a {} after my last line. No ‘new’ keyword needed to assign a Type to an object. New keyword is good for calling a constructor, if my memory serves me accurately.