# TypeScript interface extends either one or another interface

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-types

Suppose I have the following two interface

```
interface Bird {
    type: 'bird';
    flyingSpeed: number;
}
```

```
interface Horse {
    type: 'horse';
    runningSpeed: number;
}
```

Now I want to create another interface that will extend either the `Bird` or `Horse` interface. I know that it's possible by using type. I am just curious about whether it is possible by using an interface or not like the following

```
interface Animal extends Bird | Horse {
    name: string
}
```

Comment: Possibly, this post refers to the same question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865620/multiple-inheritance-workarounds

Comment: What should `Animal` behave like? `(Animal extends Bird) & (Animal extends Horse)` or `Animal extends (Bird & Horse)`? Something else?

Comment: As asked, this is impossible.  An interface can only be built on a single object type (or intersection of object types) with statically known members.  A union is not such a type, so this is not possible.  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz You know type support either A or B  option. So I just wondering whether it's also possible in the case of interface or not?

Comment: Maybe there's a communication barrier here? My response to this comment would be nearly identical to my previous comment.  Let me try again: No, it is impossible.  What you are calling "A or B" is a **union**, and interfaces cannot extend unions.  Does that make sense now?  If so, I will write an answer post.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would take the opposite way.
I would first create an abstract interface of the `Animal` and then create individual subspecies from it.
The `AnimaSpecies` type is not mandatory, you can skip it and define the type only in `Bird` and `Horse`.

```
type AnimaSpecies = 'bird' | 'horse';

interface Animal {
    name: string,
    type: AnimaSpecies;
}

interface Bird extends Animal {
    type: 'bird';
    flyingSpeed: number;
}

interface Horse extends Animal {
    type: 'horse';
    runningSpeed: number;
}
```