# Error "Type IFoo<T> requires a construct signature but type Foo<T> lacks one" when implementing a newable generic interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a newable generic interface that looks something like that:

```
interface IFoo<T> {
    new (scope: T);
}
```

When I try to implement it in a class, like so:

```
class BaseFoo<T> implements IFoo<T> {
    constructor(scope: T) {

    }
}
```

I get an error:
"Class BaseFoo declares interface IFoo but does not implement it:
 Type 'IFoo' requires a construct signature, but type 'BaseFoo' lacks one."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does typescript interfaces with construct signatures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407036/how-does-typescript-interfaces-with-construct-signatures-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you wouldn't put construction details on an interface. How and object is constructed is not part of its contract.

The interface is the promise of certain behaviour, so you might use:

```
interface IFoo<T> {
    getById (id: number) T;
}
```

I can now supply any implementation of the interface whatever the constructor because it can perform the operation I need.

If you need a public handle on the item, you might go so far as putting the properties on the interface:

```
interface IFoo<T> {
    scope: T;
}
```

The reason you *can* define constructors on an interface in TypeScript is that interfaces are used to write declarations for libraries and external code - so it is useful to be able to write interfaces for things that you can't represent as a TypeScript class.