# Type check class reference based on interface

Tags: typescript

I want to pass a class reference to a function that will create and return an instance of that class. However, I want to type-check the class passed in based on an interface it implements.

The [accepted answer to 'How does typescript interfaces with construct signatures work?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13408029/619602) describes a way which relies on structural type-checking based on the constructor's signature alone. Sure, that question is specific to constructor signatures, so perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree, because in my example:

1. Classes which implement `IHappyController` don't share the same constructor signature.
2. False positives are easily produced when constructors in unrelated interfaces match.

   ```
   interface IHappyController
   {
     name:string;
   }

   interface IHappyControllerConstructable
   {
     // This constructor is compatible with JoyfulController
     new ( name:String, joyfulSong:string, joyfulColor:string ):IHappyController;

     // This constructor is compatible with DelightfulController
     //new ( name:String, time:Date ):IHappyController;
   }

   interface ISadController
   {
     name:string;
     reason:string;
   }

   interface ISadControllerConstructable
   {
     // This constructor is compatible with DismalController, signature is same as DelightfulController
     new ( name:String, time:Date ):ISadController;
   }

   class JoyfulController implements IHappyController
   {
     constructor( public name:string, joyfulSong:string, joyfulColor:string )
     {

     }
   }

   class DelightfulController implements IHappyController
   {
     constructor( public name:string, time:Date )
     {

     }
   }

   class DismalController implements ISadController
   {
     reason:string;

     constructor( public name:string, time:Date )
     {

     }
   }

   // happyMaker should return an instance of the passed class, but only if the instance implements IHappyController
   var happyMaker = ( clazz:IHappyControllerConstructable ):IHappyController => {
     var instance:IHappyController = ServiceLocator.getByClass( clazz );
     return instance;
   }

   happyMaker(JoyfulController);       // Expect Success, it implements IHappyController
   happyMaker(DelightfulController);   // Expect Success, it implements IHappyController
   happyMaker(DismalController);       // Expect Error, it implements ISadController
   ```

### A simpler solution?

I'm guessing (hoping) there's a simpler solution that doens't rely on `I*Constructable` interfaces at all. But what should the method signature of `happyMaker()` be?

```
interface IHappyController
{
  name:string;
}

interface ISadController
{
  name:string;
  reason:string;
}

class JoyfulController implements IHappyController
{
  constructor( public name:string, joyfulSong:string, joyfulColor:string )
  {

  }
}

class DelightfulController implements IHappyController
{
  constructor( public name:string, time:Date )
  {

  }
}

class DismalController implements ISadController
{
  reason:string;

  constructor( public name:string, time:Date )
  {

  }
}

// happyMaker should return an instance of the passed class, but only if the instance implements IHappyController
var happyMaker = ( clazz:/* WHAT GOES HERE? */ ):IHappyController => {
  var instance:IHappyController = ServiceLocator.getByClass( clazz );
  return instance;
}

happyMaker(JoyfulController);       // Expect Success, it implements IHappyController
happyMaker(DelightfulController);   // Expect Success, it implements IHappyController
happyMaker(DismalController);       // Expect Error, it implements ISadController
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example as written can't work because `ISadController` is a subtype of `IHappyController` and TypeScript uses structural typing, so anything that's valid to do with an `IHappyController` is going to be valid to do with an `ISadController`.

If you tweak `IHappyController` so that it's not a supertype of `ISadController`, though, you can do this:

```
interface IHappyController {
  happyName: string;
}

interface ISadController {
  name:string;
  reason:string;
}

class JoyfulController implements IHappyController {
  constructor(public happyName:string, joyfulSong:string, joyfulColor:string) { }
}

class DelightfulController implements IHappyController {
  constructor(public happyName:string, time:Date) { }
}

class DismalController implements ISadController {
  reason:string;
  constructor(public name:string, time:Date) { }
}

declare var ServiceLocator;
var happyMaker = <T extends IHappyController>( clazz: { new(...args: any[]): T } ): T => {
  var instance = ServiceLocator.getByClass( clazz );
  return <T>instance;
}

happyMaker(JoyfulController); // OK
happyMaker(DelightfulController); // OK
happyMaker(DismalController); // Error
```

Comment: That's great, thx! As per your example, what are the advantages to using a generic type extending IHappyController? Instead of just `happyMaker = ( clazz: { new(...args: any[]): IHappyController } ):IHappyController`

Comment: Should have written the return type there as `T`. That would make `happyMaker` fully generic (returns a `JoyfulController` instance when passed in that constructor)

Comment: Gotcha. Very nice, makes sense.