# Type X is not a 'constructor function type' (TS2507)

Tags: typescript, typescript1.6

While designing a definition file, I came across this error (TS2507).

How can I specify a type to be a 'constructor function type' ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are defining an interface, you can declare that it is a constructor like such:

```
interface SomeInterface {
  new(someParam: any): SomeInterface
}
```

This is useful when you are defining typings for already existing JS libraries. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13408029/3124288) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

well, if you take a look at the original definition of the error (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/tests/baselines/reference/classExtendingPrimitive.errors.txt) you'll see that the 'undefined' is hardcoded within this error message. 
And undefined was never a valid constructor type (even in js). So, I guess you don't need to do anything but ensure that you pass a valid constructor and not undefined resp. null. An example for such a problem can be found here: https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/52f67024282ae3a0890009b0