# Generics in Typescript - Undefined T

Tags: javascript, generics, typescript

Having a problem with Typescript's Generics where the type is undefined in the scope of the generic function or class. I can't find any documentation on this though I would assume it is by design. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to, type-safely?

```
function test<T>() {
    return new T();
}

class TestClass<T> {
    public build(): T {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Link to Play:

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=function%20test%3CT%3E()%20%7B%0A%09return%20new%20T()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20TestClass%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%09public%20build()%3A%20T%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20new%20T()%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A

Comment: For explanation of non-generic version, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407036/how-does-typescript-interfaces-with-construct-signatures-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript generics (unlike other languages like C#) are compile time only. So you cannot use them in *runtime positions* e.g. `new T`.

> Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to, type-safely

Pass the constructor *explicitly*. e.g.

```
class TestClass<T> {
    public build(x:{new ():T}): T {
        return new x();
    }
}
```

Here `x:{new ():T}` I am saying that `x` is something that when called with `new` gives an instance of `T`.