# What does new?() mean in typescript?

Tags: generics, typescript

I have this code snippet in typescript playground:

```
interface IFoo {
    new?():string;

}

class Foo implements IFoo {
    new() {
     return 'sss'; 
    }

}
```

I have to put "?" in the interface method new, otherwise it will show compile error. I cannot figure out why.

Update:
  the original question is not a good way of using new, so I post a more realistic and practical way of using the above mentioned new():

```
interface IUser {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface UserConstructable {
  new (id: number, name: string, ...keys: any[]): IUser;
}

class User implements IUser {
  constructor(public id: number, public name: string) {

  }
}

class Employee implements IUser {
  constructor(public id: number, public name: string, 
    private manager: string) {

  }
}


class UserFactory {
   private static _idx: number = 0;
   static makeUser(n: UserConstructable): IUser {
      let newId = UserFactory._idx++;

      return new n(newId, 'user-' + newId, 'manager-' + newId);
   } 
}

console.log(UserFactory.makeUser(User));
console.log(UserFactory.makeUser(User));
console.log(UserFactory.makeUser(Employee));
```

Comment: Isn't it just a name of the function?

Comment: Did you try giving the implementation an explicit return type? It might be defaulting to _any_.

Comment: @Trygve Skogsholm, I am not sure about your comments. If I change method name from "new" to something else, like "aNew", removing ? from interface won't cause compile error.

Comment: mmm, perhaps new can only return Foo?

Comment: @Trygve Skogsholm, I guess you are right. I dig a little bit and find this might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407036/how-does-typescript-interfaces-with-construct-signatures-work

Answer (score 4):

Let's break this into a couple of parts... I know that you already know some of this, but I'm trying to be complete.

```
1..2.3..4
new?():string;
```

1. In this specific context, `new` is not a keyword, it is just a method name... due to the next item in this list...
2. The `?` makes this optional (i.e. you can implement the interface without implementing this method).
3. The `()` means `new` is a method.
4. The return type is a string

Example

```
class Foo implements IFoo {
    new() {
        return 'sss'; 
    }
}

class Bar implements IFoo {
    // Because new is optional, you don't have to implement it
}
```

If you omit the `?`, then you are using `new` as a keyword - but TypeScript interprets the code in your example as a simple method.

On the whole, though, I'd avoid naming a member with something that is known as a reserved word.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. I have one little thing t point out that, contrary to your first comment, new has some special meaning in typescript, though it might not be a keyword. Otherwise, if you replace it with method name "aNew" and the presence of ? does not matter, compilation wise.

Comment: The `?` is the all-important part of your question. With the `?` in this interface, `new` would indeed be a keyword, but when you append `?` it changes the way the compiler interprets the declaration and `new` becomes a simple method rather than a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, functions are objects, and thus typescript interfaces should also be able to match functions. This is why we get those weird interfaces.

```
interface SomeFunc {
  (key: string): boolean;
  (key: number): boolean;
}
```

That interface will only match a function that accepts either a string or a number and returns a boolean.

Now consider the case of constructor functions (i.e. classes in ES5-).

```
function MyClass() {
  this.prop = value;
}
let myClass = new MyClass;
```

We need a way to create an interface that matches the signature of `MyClass` function. This is where we get the `new` function in interfaces.

```
interface IFoo {
  new (key: string): {key:string};
}

function someFunction(key: string) { // doesn't match IFoo
  return {key};
}

var someObject = { // still doesn't match IFoo
  new(key: string) { 
    return {key};
  },
};

function MyClass(key: string) { // matches IFoo! must be called like `new MyClass()`
  this.key = key;
}
```

so you can say that the signature of function `new` must match the signature of the class constructor.

```
interface IFoo {
  new(key: string): {};
}
class Foo implements IFoo { // works ok
  constructor(key: string) { // you can't return anything
  }
}
```

I think what you wanted to do is this:

```
interface IFoo {
  new: () => string;
}
```

i.e. `IFoo` should have a property called `new` which is a function that returns a string.