# Are MetaClasses not possible in Typescript

Tags: typescript

For example, the following won't compile [(link to typescript playground example)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=declare%20class%20ClassFactory%20%7B%0A%09constructor()%3B%0A%09new()%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20User%20%3D%20new%20ClassFactory()%3B%0Aconst%20user%20%3D%20new%20User()%3B%20%0A):

```
declare class ClassFactory {
    constructor();
    new(): any;
}

const User = new ClassFactory();
const user = new User();
```

Resulting error:

```
Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

Do I need additional annotations? How can I declare a MetaClass? I was assuming that `new(): any;` was taken to be a prototype method on the class, thus being the instances construct pattern.

*EDIT*: fixed link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are possible. Here is a quick example:

```
declare class User{}
declare interface ClassFactory {
    new(): typeof User;
}
declare var ClassFactory: ClassFactory;

const UserClass = new ClassFactory();
const user = new UserClass(); // user has type `User`
```

## An explanation of various parts

- To declare that "this thing when called with `new` will return something" you cannot use a `class`. Hence  `interface ClassFactory`
- To use such a declaration from the *variable* namespace you need a variable. Hence `var ClassFactory`
- To say that something is a `class` not an *instance* of the class you cannot do `: User` you need to get the type of the class. Hence `typeof User`.

## More

A key concept here used multiple times is that of declaration spaces. That is covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html

Comment: Thanks! Interesting, so basically the `new(): <type>` construct can't work with classes, as they must return an instance of the class itself?

Comment: @BenSouthgate yes 

Comment: one follow up, actually, while the above works as an interface to existing javascript files, it is not actually implementable in typescript if I am understanding the answer to this question correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407036/how-does-typescript-interfaces-with-construct-signatures-work

Comment: `it is not actually implementable in typescript`. Not implementable as a *class*. But can be implemented as a function with a type assertion telling the compiler of the intent.

Comment: gotcha, so if you want to have a class factory, it has to be a function that returns the class (without using a `new` expression) as [non-void, non-class functions cannot be called with `new`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%0Afunction%20classFactory()%20%7B%0A%09return%20new%20A%3B%09%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0A%09%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20new%20classFactory()%3B)