# In TypeScript, how do I implement an interface with (a: type, b:type): any?

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, typescript1.8, tslint

Specifically, I'm trying to setup server sided typescript compilation for express.

One of the interfaces exposed is RequestHandler, with the following structure:

```
// express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts

declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
  ...

  interface RequestHandler {
    (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): any;
  }
}
```

I wrote the following class:

```
import * as express from "express";

class PageNotFound implements express.RequestHandler {

  constructor (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) {
    let viewFilePath: string = "404";
    let statusCode: number = 404;
    let result: Object = {
      status: statusCode,
    };

    res.status(statusCode);
    res.render(viewFilePath, {}, function (err: Error, html: string): void {
      if (err) {
        res.status(statusCode).json(result);
      }
      res.send(html);
    });
  }
}
```

However, this throws the error:

`error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof PageNotFound' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandler'.
  Type 'typeof PageNotFound' provides no match for the signature '(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): any'`

Any suggestions out there? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RequestHandler is an interface that is specifying something with a call signature, which classes cannot implement.  You want a regular function:

```
function pageNotFound(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) {
    ...
}
```

If the interface had `new` in front of the method signature, it would be defining the shape of the constructor of your class, but that isn't the case.

Another way to think about it is this: when you use a class, you're defining a function that must be called with `new`.  Is Express going to call "new PageNotFound(...)" or is it calling "pageNotFound(...)"?

As Ryan Cavanaugh, one of the TypeScript developers, put it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407036/how-does-typescript-interfaces-with-construct-signatures-work):

> More formally, a class implementing an interface is a contract on what an instance of the class has... – Ryan Cavanaugh Nov 15 '12 at 23:57

Comment: That is correct. I also added the type definition `: void` and `"use strict";` due to tslint complaining. Thanks, Alan!

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep it simple, classes are for objects that are used more than once. The module `express` provides for you the Router object with the correct properties.

```
import * as express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Express'
    })
});

export = router;
```