# constructor provides no match for signature new

Tags: typescript

i have a "compilation" problem in this case :

```
interface IDataObjectConstructor {
    new (objJSON?: any): myDataObject;
}

class myDataObject implements IDataObjectConstructor {
    constructor(objJSON: any = null) {
        for (var prop in objJSON) {
            this[prop] = objJSON[prop];
        }
    }
}
```

it say :

> class 'myDataObject' incorrectly implements interface 'IDataObjectConstructor'.
>
> Type 'myDataObject' provides no match for signature 'new (objJSON?: any) : myDataObject'

Finally i want to use this object like this :

```
class viewModelList<T extends myDataObject>{
    item: T;
    constructor(itemType: T) { this.item = itemType; }

    itemBuilder(json?) { return new this.item(json); }
}

class derivedDataObject extends myDataObject{
    constructor(objJSON: any = null) { super(objJSON); }
}

class derivedViewModelList extends viewModelList<derivedDataObject>{

    constructor() { super(derivedDataObject); }
}

let oManager = new derivedViewModelList();
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13408029/1263942). TD;LR;: Construct signatures in interfaces are not implementable in classes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does typescript interfaces with construct signatures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407036/how-does-typescript-interfaces-with-construct-signatures-work)

Answer (score 31):

## Difference between the static and instance sides of classes

When working with classes and interfaces, it helps to keep in mind that a class has two types: the type of the **static side** and the type of the **instance** side. You may notice that if you create an interface with a construct signature and try to create a class that implements this interface you get an error:

```
interface ClockConstructor {
    new (hour: number, minute: number);
}

class Clock implements ClockConstructor { // error
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { } 
}
```

This is because *when a class implements an interface*, *only the instance side of the class is checked*. Since *the constructor sits in the static side*, it is not included in this check.

Instead, you would need to work with the static side of the class directly. In this example, we *define two interfaces*, **ClockConstructor for the constructor** and **ClockInterface for the instance methods**. Then for convenience we define a constructor function createClock that creates instances of the type that is passed to it.

```
interface ClockConstructor {
    new (hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface;
}
interface ClockInterface {
    tick();
}

function createClock(ctor: ClockConstructor, hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface {
    return new ctor(hour, minute);
}

class DigitalClock implements ClockInterface {
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
    tick() {
        console.log("beep beep");
    }
}
class AnalogClock implements ClockInterface {
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
    tick() {
        console.log("tick tock");
    }
}

let digital = createClock(DigitalClock, 12, 17);
let analog = createClock(AnalogClock, 7, 32);
```

Because `createClock`’s first parameter is of type ClockConstructor, in `createClock(AnalogClock, 7, 32)`, it checks that AnalogClock has the correct constructor signature.

[See the documentation for more.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need your class to implement the constructor interface, that happens automatically.

For example:

```
interface IDataObjectConstructor {
    new (objJSON?: any): myDataObject;
}

class myDataObject {
    constructor(objJSON: any = null) {
        for (var prop in objJSON) {
            this[prop] = objJSON[prop];
        }
    }
}

function factory(ctor: IDataObjectConstructor) {
    return new ctor();
}

let o = factory(myDataObject);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IDataObjectConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20(objJSON%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20myDataObject%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20myDataObject%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(objJSON%3A%20any%20%3D%20null)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(var%20prop%20in%20objJSON)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Bprop%5D%20%3D%20objJSON%5Bprop%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20factory(ctor%3A%20IDataObjectConstructor)%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20new%20ctor()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20o%20%3D%20factory(myDataObject)%3B))

The `factory` function expects an `IDataObjectConstructor` and we're passing the class itself and you don't get any compilation errors even though your class isn't declared to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but i need to implement because i use this class in another like this :

class viewModelListe<T extends dataObject>{
    item: T;

        itemBuilder(json?) {
                return  this.item(json);
        }

}

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Please edit your question and add the code for this other case

Comment: @Clemsouz your snippet there doesn't use the interface, it simply says the type `T` extends `dataObject`.. so the above example should work there.

having said that, this answer improperly addresses the issue you're seeing in compilation and the concept of automatic implementation of a constructor interface is incorrect.. 

if the constructor was changed to `objJSON?: string` neither `factory(myDataObject)` nor `return new ctor()` would present an issue with a bad constructor signature on `myDataObject`..

Comment: additionally, if you were to change `factor` method to return `new ctor({ name : ""})` and `IDataObjectConstructor` to have a more specific signature (like any other type then `any`), you would see a warning on `new ctor({ name :""});` (not `factory(myDataObject)` mind you) but it would compile and construct an instance of myDataObject properly..

Comment: still, this is the expected implementation pattern for this.. `IDataObjectConstructor` is not an interface for implementation.  review `angular.IServiceProvider` and `angular.IServiceProviderClass` with the consideration of that pattern @NitzanTomer provided in his answer.