# Assign an ES5 constructor function to a variable of constructor type

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-5

This code has a possibility of existing in ES5 and it executes perfectly:

```js
const ctor = function () {
    return {
        prop: 'value'
    };
};

const obj = new ctor();

console.log(obj);
```

Here is my attempt to type it:

```
interface SomeClass {
    new(...args: any[]): { prop: string };
}

const ctor: SomeClass = function () {
    return {
        prop: 'value'
    };
}

const obj = new ctor();

console.log(obj);
```

This does not compile in TypeScript which throws:

```
Type '() => { prop: string; }' is not assignable to type 'SomeClass'.
  Type '() => { prop: string; }' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any[]): { prop: string; }'.(2322)
```

Does TypeScript purposely not support ES5 syntax or am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you adding this? `new(...args: any[])`? You're defining a function in the type with variadic parameters

Comment: It is supposed to be able to take functions with no parameters. Removing that doesn't fix the problem btw

Comment: This is not supported by Typescript AFAIK. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51237200/17560229)

Comment: @whygee indeed it looks like it's not supported

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the new() type checking is done for the instance of the class, and for the constructor is static, which has a different type. More info here: [constructor provides no match for signature new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654840/constructor-provides-no-match-for-signature-new/53056911)

```
interface ConstructorInterface {
    new(...args: any[]): SomeOtherInterface
}

interface SomeOtherInterface {
   method(): {prop: string}
}

class Ctor implements SomeOtherInterface {
    method() {
        return {prop: "test"};
    }
}

const obj = new Ctor();
console.log(obj);
```

That will fix the issue, it also works because you can omit the constructor.

You can also add a function that returns an instance that implements your interface.

```
function createCtor(ctor: ConstructorInterface): SomeOtherInterface {
    return new ctor();
}

const obj1 = createCtor(Ctor);
console.log(obj1);
```

Comment: In your example `SomeInterface` is not being used anywhere. Also you are using the ES6 syntax when my question is about ES5

Comment: Updated it. Regarding ES6 syntax, it's actually TypeScript.

Comment: So you are saying that TypeScript doesn't support ES5 source code?

Comment: I answered your question of implementing it with TypeScript, it's not what you wanted?

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. TypeScript is a typing layer over JavaScript. I expect it to be able to type any JavaScript code, even if written in ES5 but I am not able to type an ES5 constructor. Is it something not supported by TypeScript or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I gave you the way you can do something like you want, i.e. a solution. What's the problem with the code I shared? If you want to do something not supported by the language, i.e. what you posed, no it's not going to work.