# Trying to create object based on generic type - Argument of type 'typeof X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new (...args: any[]) => typeof X'

Tags: typescript, generics

What I want to achieve is to have a function with a generic type `T` and to be able to create objects of said type.

I figured I had to use [*construct signatures*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) and I thought that I could use a [*generic constraint*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to define that my class needs a constructor.
Yet, this did not work, as shown in *Example 1*.
Instead, if I define my function's parameter to have the construct signature as type instead of using a generic constraint, it suddenly work.

I still cannot make out why Example 1 does not work.
I found [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654840/constructor-provides-no-match-for-signature-new) which talks about things such as *static side* and *instance side* of a class, which are in turn in more detail [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399613/what-is-exactly-the-static-side-and-the-instance-side-in-typescript). Nevertheless, I cannot make out how exactly this relates to my problem.

I thought that it might be due to the fact that `type` may describe an *instance* of `T` (and not the class itself), but then a colleague came up with *Example 3*, which (for whatever reason) *works*!

I hope somebody can shed some light on this for me.

*Example 1 (not working)*: The following does not work (`create(Person)` gives the error `Argument of type 'typeof Person' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new (...args: any[]) => typeof Person'.`:

```
class Person {
  public name: string
  constructor(name: string = '') {
    this.name = name
  }
}

function create<T extends { new(...args:any[]) : T }> (type : T) : T {
    return new type()
}

console.log(create(Person))
```

*Example 2 (working)*:

```
class Person {
  public name: string
  constructor(name: string = '') {
    this.name = name
  }
}

function create<T> (type : { new(...args:any[]) : T } ) : T { // this line has been changed
    return new type()
}

console.log(create(Person))
```

*Example 3 (working)*:

```
class Person {
  public name: string
  constructor(name: string = '') {
    this.name = name
  }
}

function create<T extends { new(...args:any[]) : any }> (type : T) : InstanceType<T> { // this line has been changed
    return new type()
}

console.log(create(Person))
```

Comment: On the face of it, `T extends { new(...args: any[]): T` means that if you have a value `type` of type `T`, you could write `new type()` and it would result in a value of type `T`. Meaning you could write `new (new type())()` or `new (new (new (new type())())())()` etc.  Is that what the `Person` constructor does? No, it just makes `Person` instances and those are not themselves constructors.  That's why example 1 fails, and neither of your other examples have that issue. Does that explain things sufficiently (and I'd write up a more detailed answer) or is there still something missing?