# Interface that enforces a constructor signature

Tags: typescript

Why does class `C`

```
class C implements N, M {
  constructor(public a: number) {}
}
```

not satisfy the the interfaces `M` or `N`?

```
interface M {
  constructor(a: number)
}
interface N {
  new(a: number)
}
```

**How do I write an interface** that `C` satisfies?

Comment: That's a related question, can't find the answer though

Comment: Your question is more succinct, but effectively the same problem; The answer is as answered in the other by @RyanCavanaugh: "Construct signatures in interfaces are not implementable in classes". the work around is also in there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13700960/1657476