# typescript: import default export from module

Tags: typescript, import, export, default

I have the following definition type file:

```
// index.d.ts
declare module 'Transformer' {
  class EditableElement {
      constructor(target: SVGPoint);
  }
  export = EditableElement;
}
```

And I want to import `EditableElement`. But when I write the following line:

```
import {EditableElement} from 'Transformer';
```

I get the next error:

*Module "Transformer" resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.*

How could I import the `EditableElement` class? Actually, I just want to make use of that class. I don't want the `import` directive to have a collateral effect in my code. I just want use it :'(

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407036/how-does-typescript-interfaces-with-construct-signatures-work

Comment: This is not "default export", it is CommonJS format.

Answer (score 33):

This falls into ES6 / CommonJS interop.

My recommendation is to not relying on interop and use the old syntax instead:

```
const EditableElement = require('Transformer')
```

If you NEED to target es6/es2015, then you can do:

```
import * as EditableElement from 'Transformer'

// with `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`
import EditableElement from 'Transformer'
```

UPDATE: with TypeScript@2.7 released, you can now do `import EditableElement from 'Transformer'` directly.

Turn on `esModuleInterop` in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: `esModuleInterop` saved my day

Answer (score 1):

`declare module`  is deprecated to use in your own typescript modules.You have to use either `export` or `export default`.

```
export class EditableElement {
      constructor(target: SVGPoint);
  }
```

For import you can use either `import {EditableElement} from 'Transformer';` or `import * as EditableElement from 'Transformer';`

Comment: Thanks. This is automatically added by the "typings" command line: typings install file:/path/to/my/package/Transformer.d.ts

Comment: Oh. I missed that it was d.ts. Maybe i was wrong. I prefer to use .ts and .tsx for declaring classes.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have reference path like that?

```
 /// <reference path="*/**/myModules.d.ts" />
 import * as m from "SomeModule";
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of this in the following way.

Scenario 1 - Export / import explicit things (Not a default export. This results in the need for wrapping your import name with '{}').

```
// Export (fileX)
export const something = 'hello world';

// Import (fileY)
import { something } from 'fileX';
```

Scenario 2 - Export / import a default (This results in no need for wrapping your import name with '{}'). The name that you choose, 'something' below, would be the alias for accessing your import.

```
// Export (fileX)
export default 'hello world';

// Import (fileY)
import something from 'fileY';
```

Comment: In scenario 1, the entity that I'm exporting and importing is a class.
When I try to use the imported class, I get `_MyExportFile.default is not a constructor.`