# Defining just the interface and type for class

Tags: typescript, react-native

I want to define just the interface and type for the class..

What am I doing?
I am creating a React Native Turbo module which require me to pass interface which extends `TurboModule`

This is class looks for which I want to write interface (this interface should extend turboModule)

```
export default class Thread {
  constructor(jsPath) {
    if (!jsPath || !jsPath.endsWith('.js')) {
      throw new Error('Invalid path for thread. Only js files are supported');
    }

    this.id = ThreadManager.startThread(jsPath.replace(".js", ""))
      .then(id => {
        DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(`Thread${id}`, (message) => {
          !!message && this.onmessage && this.onmessage(message);
        });
        return id;
      })
      .catch(err => { throw new Error(err) });
  }

  postMessage(message) {
    this.id.then(id => ThreadManager.postThreadMessage(id, message));
  }

  terminate() {
    this.id.then(ThreadManager.stopThread);
  }
}
```

This is what I have written

```
export interface ThreadInterface {
  postMessage(msg: string): void;
  onMessage(msg: string): void;
  terminate(): void;
}
interface ThreadConstructor {
  new (path: string): ThreadInterface;
}

declare let ThreadInterface: ThreadConstructor;

export interface ThreadsSpec extends TurboModule, ThreadInterface {}
```

Is this correct? also when I do this

```
class Thread implements ThreadInterface {
  constructor(jsPath:string) {

    }
```

here I have to mention jsPath as string, or else typescript consider it as any. I was expecting constructor to pick value from here:

```
  new (path: string): ThreadInterface;
```

This is based out of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46971111/10433835

Comment: It doesn't really make any sense to do that. Just have your class be `class Foo extends TurboModule implements Bar {}`, or maybe even just `class Foo extends TurboModule {}`. What is the point of defining this interface?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly as you have correctly noted, the interface you have defined **does not** check the constructor type.

Proof:

```
class Car implements ThreadInterface {
  constructor(whateverIWant: boolean) { // Problem: passes type-check
     // even though it should be string according to the interface
  }

  postMessage(msg: string): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.')
  }
  onMessage(msg: string): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.')
  }
  terminate(): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.')
  }
}
```

[The way to check constructor type is described here in the official doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#class-types) and it looks like this:

```
interface ClockConstructor {
  new (hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface;
}
 
interface ClockInterface {
  tick(): void;
}
 
const Clock: ClockConstructor = class Clock implements ClockInterface {
  constructor(h: number, m: number) {}
  tick() {
    console.log("beep beep");
  }
};
```

It is a little clumsy, but to my knowledge Typescript does not have a better way of checking constructor type. Hope this helps in your particular use case.