# Property named "new" in object literal is not accessible through dot syntax, but makes the object constructable

Tags: typescript

```
// index.ts
export const a = {
   new(a: number): number {
      return 35
   }
}

// other.ts
import {a} from "index"
a.new(35) // invalid
new a(35) // valid
```

I have an exported object literal with exported functions as properties. One of the functions is named "new". Calling a.new is invalid, but now the object literal is constructable. Is this the expected functionality? I couldn't find any documentation regarding this.

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword, you cannot use that as property keys

Comment: This looks like a bug in TypeScript and should probably be filed as such.  The emitted declaration should probably look like `{"new"(a: number): number}` instead of `{new(a: number): number}`, since the latter is a construct signature.  Do you want to file a bug there or do you want me to do it (although it might take a while for me to do it)?

Comment: @jcalz I thought TS3.5 took out the string literal hack (which I got from [an old answer of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46977622/215552) :)), but maybe that was only with `constructor`...

Comment: Which version of Typescript do you use?

It seemed to work as expected in `4.1.5`

Comment: What exactly is the problem? This seems to behave exactly how I would expect: https://tsplay.dev/wRjq5w

Comment: For those here who are missing it: the problem is that the `.d.ts` declaration file emitted by [this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wIZwLxwN4BQcxcywA7gBQYBcpArgLYBGwUAlHck61PkSUFRgMelGRwAzAFYBxAL4F5QA) is incorrect: code that consumes said declaration will see an object with a construct signature (which the original object does not have) and not a method named new (which the original object has)

Comment: Update: I have filed [ms/TS#55075](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55075) and I'll update here when I know more.

Comment: It's officially a bug in TypeScript; answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#55075](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55075).  The problem is that when `a`'s type declaration is emitted (e.g., via [the `--declaration` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#declaration)), its type is serialized as having a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) instead of having a method named `"new"`.  A construct signature *looks* like a method named `"new"`, (e.g., `{ new(arg: A): B }`), so it's easy enough to see how this occurred.  The correct way to serialize a method named `"new"` would be to emit a string literal property or computed property instead, like `{ "new"(arg: A): B }` or `{ ["new"](arg: A): B }`.

Note that microsoft/TypeScript#55075 is marked as [Help Wanted](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/labels/Help%20Wanted), meaning that anyone who is sufficiently interested in seeing it fixed might want to submit a pull request themselves (remembering to adhere to [the guidelines for contributing](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/97310107d007dd2f14f20688371b69ba76040a18/CONTRIBUTING.md#instructions-for-contributing-code)).

Until and unless this happens you will have to work around the problem by explicitly [annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) with the correct type:

```
export const a: { "new"(a: number): number } = {
  new(a: number): number {
    return 35
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://tsplay.dev/WyjKgw)