# How to rewrite the definition of a generic constructor that provides no match for the signature

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, constructor, interface

I'm writing a library to implement lazily evaluated queries of iterable types in JavaScript. I'm aware there are already available options that accomplish this, but mine is taking a drastically different approach to exposing the extension methods.

I'm having difficulty approaching a particular design challenge and was wondering if there was some work-around I hadn't thought of for resolving the issue.

My `Enumerable<T>` class definition and its interface along with a few helpers is as follows:

```
// Iterator<T> defined in lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts
interface IteratorFunction<T> {
  (this: IEnumerable<T> | void): Iterator<T>
}

interface CompareFunction<T> {
  (a: T, b: T): number
}

// inspired by pattern for ArrayConstructor in lib.es5.d.ts
interface IEnumerableConstructor {
  new <T>(iterator: IteratorFunction<T>): IEnumerable<T>
  new <T>(iterator: IteratorFunction<T>, compare: null): IEnumerable<T>
  new <T>(iterator: IteratorFunction<T>, compare: CompareFunction<T>): IOrderedEnumerable<T>

  // static methods...
}

// Symbol.compare defined in separate file as a declaration merge to SymbolConstructor
interface IOrderedEnumerable<T> extends IEnumerable<T> {
  readonly [Symbol.compare]: CompareFunction<T>

  // overrides for thenBy()...
}

// IterableIterator<T> defined in lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts
interface IEnumerable<T> extends IterableIterator<T> {
  // member methods...
}

class Enumerable<T> implements IEnumerableConstructor {
  readonly [Symbol.iterator]: IteratorFunction<T>
  readonly [Symbol.compare]: (null | CompareFunction<T>)

  constructor (iterator: IteratorFunction<T>)
  constructor (iterator: IteratorFunction<T>, compare: (null | CompareFunction<T>) = null) {
    this[Symbol.iterator] = iterator
    this[Symbol.compare] = compare
  }
}
```

The problem is that

```
constructor (iterator: IteratorFunction<T>)
```

refers to the hypothetical definition

```
new (iterator: IteratorFunction<T>): IEnumerable<T>
```

as opposed to the provided definition

```
new <T>(iterator: IteratorFunction<T>): IEnumerable<T>
```

and so on for the other overloaded declarations in `IEnumerable<T>`, providing me the error

> Type '`Enumerable<T>`' provides no match for the signature '`new <T>(iterator: IteratorFunction<T>): IEnumerable<T>`'.

I considered changing the `IEnumerableConstructor` class to be generic as well, but then I run into a problem later when I try to do this:

```
declare global {
  // ...

  interface ArrayConstructor extends IEnumerableConstructor/*<T>*/ { } // illegal!
  interface MapConstructor extends IEnumerableConstructor { }
  interface SetConstructor extends IEnumerableConstructor { }
  interface StringConstructor extends IEnumerableConstructor { }
  interface TypedArrayConstructor extends IEnumerableConstructor { }

  interface Array<T> extends IEnumerable<T> { }
  interface Map<K, V> extends IEnumerable<[K, V]> { }
  interface Set<T> extends IEnumerable<T> { }
  interface String extends IEnumerable<string> { }
  interface TypedArray extends IEnumerable<number> { }
}
```

To clarify, I've declared `TypedArray` as the class that `Int8Array` and so on extend, as per the ECMAScript specification (but the typings for it are not provided in TypeScript `lib.*.d.ts` files since it's never directly used, which is understandable).

As I've said, this library implementation is a drastically different approach to exposing extension methods to built-ins in JavaScript and I'm aware of all the pitfalls, but right now I'm looking for a way to provide a definition for the class `Enumerable<T>` constructor that respects the generic type of `IEnumerable<T>`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IEnumerableConstructor` has construct signature, [such interface can not be directly implemented by a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13408029/43848).

But in TypeScript, a class does not need to be explicitly declared as implementing some interface - after all, the type system is structural and you can just use your class in place where the interface is required, provided that it's compatible.

From what I understand in your code, `Enumerable<T>` must in fact implement `IEnumerable<T>`, because that's the type the construct signature in `interface IEnumerableConstructor` is declared to produce. So it should have `next()` method, and then it seems to work if you simply omit `implements IEnumerableConstructor` (but it wouldn't hurt if you replace it with `implements IEnumerable`, to make the compiler check that class implements that interface properly):

```
class Enumerable<T>  implements IEnumerable<T> {
  readonly [Symbol.iterator]: IteratorFunction<T>
  readonly compare: (null | CompareFunction<T>)

  constructor (iterator: IteratorFunction<T>)
  constructor (iterator: IteratorFunction<T>, compare?: (null | CompareFunction<T>)) {
    this[Symbol.iterator] = iterator
    this.compare = compare
    }

    next(): IteratorResult<T> {
        return undefined;
    }
}

const C: IEnumerableConstructor = Enumerable;

type A = { a: string };
let a: A[];

const c = new C(a.values); // inferred as const c: IEnumerable<A>
```

Comment: Thanks, the methods weren't an issue, as I omitted those declarations and definitions for brevity. However, when I tried to get this to work, I had to remove `extends IterableIterator<T>` from `interface IEnumerable<T>`, otherwise there was a conflict assigning to `this[Symbol.iterator]`. I have yet to test if I can still pass an `IEnumerable<T>` as the target of a `for...of` loop, but I can cross that bridge when I come to it. Thanks for this enlightening explanation!

Comment: I've been working recently on this again, and I've realized a few important things. Using the builtin library definitions as a reference, it seems that the standard practice is to omit the `constructor` signature from `interface`s in favor of using the `new` signature in the interface's respective `...Constructor` interface. Secondly, I've noted that the sole purpose of `IEnumerable` is to define the subset of `Enumerable` that is [contravariant](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/#toc-contravariance) to `Array`, `Map`, `Set`, `String` and `TypedArray`.