# Implement an overloaded callable interface in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, interface

The discussion in [implement callable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66375915/can-a-typescript-class-implement-a-callable-interface) is useful but does not completely my answer my question.

```
interface lol {
    (a: number): (b: number) => string
    // (a: string): (b: string) => string  // overloaded will not work
}
let l: lol = function(a: number) {
  return (b: number) => {
    return (a + b).toString()
  }
}
```

This snippet works but when the overloaded function is uncommented it fails. I've tried various methods and haven't figure out how to implement the overloaded version.

A slightly convoluted but real world implementation I'm trying to understand is [`fp-ts` style interfaces](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/b40a2a4a0dce345b87f391aaf88c56711be20d4c/src/Traversable.ts#L141-L164). Ignoring the complex types it's an overloaded callable interface is what I understand. How would such a thing have a concrete implementation.

```
export interface Traverse1<T extends URIS> {
  <F extends URIS4>(F: Applicative4<F>): <A, S, R, E, B>(
    ta: Kind<T, A>,
    f: (a: A) => Kind4<F, S, R, E, B>
  ) => Kind4<F, S, R, E, Kind<T, B>>
  <F extends URIS3>(F: Applicative3<F>): <A, R, E, B>(
    ta: Kind<T, A>,
    f: (a: A) => Kind3<F, R, E, B>
  ) => Kind3<F, R, E, Kind<T, B>>
  <F extends URIS3, E>(F: Applicative3C<F, E>): <A, R, B>(
    ta: Kind<T, A>,
    f: (a: A) => Kind3<F, R, E, B>
  ) => Kind3<F, R, E, Kind<T, B>>
  <F extends URIS2>(F: Applicative2<F>): <A, E, B>(
    ta: Kind<T, A>,
    f: (a: A) => Kind2<F, E, B>
  ) => Kind2<F, E, Kind<T, B>>
  <F extends URIS2, E>(F: Applicative2C<F, E>): <A, B>(
    ta: Kind<T, A>,
    f: (a: A) => Kind2<F, E, B>
  ) => Kind2<F, E, Kind<T, B>>
  <F extends URIS>(F: Applicative1<F>): <A, B>(ta: Kind<T, A>, f: (a: A) => Kind<F, B>) => Kind<F, Kind<T, B>>
  <F>(F: Applicative<F>): <A, B>(ta: Kind<T, A>, f: (a: A) => HKT<F, B>) => HKT<F, Kind<T, B>>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The implementation declaration must satisfy all of the overloads stated by the interface so, in your case, it might end up looking something like this:

```js
let l: lol = function <T extends number | string>(a: T): (b: T) => string {
    throw Error("not implemented");
}
```

In my experience, you'll need to do a lot of type-checking and casting to get the implementation right.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDYHtXIN4ChkHIAUcAXMiAK4C2ARtAJTlG3lV2PIC8AfMgM5gooAOb5CJcoOEgRTYqwFDRDbn2mjcAX1y5UEMGnIYsXZDEogEYYOhDIAPABVkEAB6QQAE34Ua9KGQAHyUZER5JZCd5FnJotVDRHHECMAALKHQAd2QAUShMqCIAIhB0Q2BqAAd9aghwCC9ihgBubV0EO0FzAEZuNCIANgZcAHpRwmQAPQB+XE6QbpgAJn7UEuaxicJZoA)

Comment: Aah now I get it. Atleast in the `fp-ts` example by using `<F extends ...>` some overloads can be eliminated and not need to be implemented. Adding possible solution as separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

After @spender's helpful explanation I realized what the fp-ts style interface is actually doing. By having `<F extends ...>` check it is possible to resolve the overloaded functions to a single concrete implementation as in the example below.

```
interface lol {
    <T extends number>(a: T): (b: T) => string
    <T extends string>(a: T): (b: T) => string
}

let l: lol = function(a: number) {
    return (b: number) => {
        return (a + b).toString()
    }
}
```

This instantiates the `T` as number so the `<T extends string>` overloading is never resolved (?? is that the right word for it).