# TypeScript: Class incorrectly implements interface, mistmatched constructor

Tags: typescript, class, constructor, interface, implements

I have an interface like this:

```
interface Foo {
  new (...args: any[]): any;
}
```

I want a class implementing `Foo` to have to have a constructor, but in my case, I don't need the constructor to have any specific arguments or return. I tried to implement the constructor like this:

```
class Bar implements Foo {
  private myNum: number;

  constructor(myNum: number) {
    this.myNum = myNum;
  }
}
```

I would expect this to work, but I get this error from TypeScript:

```
Class 'Bar' incorrectly implements interface 'Foo'.
  Type 'Bar' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any[]): any'
```

Why does the signature not match?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does interfaces with construct signatures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407036/how-does-interfaces-with-construct-signatures-work)

Comment: @crashmstr While that question is trying to get implementations to match a specific signature, I'm just trying to enforce that there is some kind of constructor, it doesn't matter what it is.

Comment: From the accepted answer: "Construct signatures in interfaces **are not implementable in classes;** they're only for defining existing JS APIs that define a 'new'-able function."

Comment: Another answer from that question: "Well an interface with a construct signature is not meant to be implemented by any class(at first glance this might look weird for guys with C#/Java background like me but give it a chance). It is slightly different."

Comment: So it seems to me that it cannot be done, regardless of specific or general signatures, and that question is definitely related if not this being a duplicate of it.