# Write class declaration for jsdoc

Tags: typescript, class, declaration, jsdoc

I write a simple class and a declaration for it. Then I use jsdoc to specify the type of lib.

```
// index.ts
class VjsccXX {
  el: HTMLElement
  text: string
  show: boolean

  constructor(el: HTMLElement, text: string, show = true) {
    this.el = el
    this.text = text
    this.show = show

    this.el.classList.add('vjsscc-xx')

    if (!show) {
      this.el.style.display = 'none'
    }

    console.log('xx is ready')
  }
  hide() {
    this.el.style.display = 'none'
  }
  tex() {
    this.el.innerHTML = this.text
  }
}

export default VjsccXX
```

```
// index.d.ts
declare class VjsccXX {
  el: HTMLElement
  text: string
  show: boolean
  hide(): void
  tex(): void
  constructor(el: HTMLElement, text: string, show?: boolean)
}

export = VjsccXX
```

```js
// test.js
/** @type {import('..')} */
const VjsccXX = window.VjsccXX
```

[image]

But as the photo shown above, `VjsccXX` become a instance rather than a class. So how to deal with it?

======================= Some Update ==========================

The image shown above use a `window.VjsccXX` because its html file include a umd bundle. And its type is not right because `VjsccXX` should be a class constructor rather than a class instance which has prototype properties.

Then I write another ts file to see its type:

[image]

Maybe I could write like that?

======================= Another update ============================

Also work with `cjs`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Maybe it is the problem of jsdoc?

Comment: What would you expect to have? You are creating a variable with the same name as your class definition and indicate with `@type` that it has the type of your class. Everything seems to be working as expected here.

Comment: Becasue after `umd` build, the `VjsccXX` will be added to `window`. And I declare a new variable with same name is no conflict. Then I use jsdoc to specific the type of it to get the right type. And its type is not right, `VjsccXX` should be a constructor rahter than a instance which has properties on class prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to use `typeof` here:

```
// test.js
/** @type {typeof import('..')} */
const VjsccXX = window.VjsccXX
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

What about creating an interface instead of a class declaration in `index.d.ts`?

```js
// index.d.ts
export interface IVjsccXX {
  el: HTMLElement;
  text: string;
  show: boolean;
  hide(): void;
  tex(): void;
}
```

Then you may use it in jsdocs:

```js
// test.js
/** @type {import('..').IVjsccXX} */
const VjsccXX = window.VjsccXX;
```

However, the `constructor` handling for interfaces in TS is a mess to me, if interested you may refer to [How does interfaces with construct signatures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407036/how-does-interfaces-with-construct-signatures-work) for details.